# Sending an email through Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I am trying to send an email through Python. I can get the email to display, but when I switch to send I get an error. This happens when I run this on a virtual machine. When I run on my laptop it works fine.

My Code:

```
#send email
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "mysubject"
newMail.HTMLBody = "mybody"
newMail.To  = "myemail@gmail.com"
newMail.Send()
```

My error:

```
newMail.Send()
File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

I created a seperate file to get more info on the error:

```
import win32api
e_msg = win32api.FormatMessage(-2147457260)
print e_msg.decode('CP1251')
```

This yields the message:

```
pywintypes.error: (317, 'FormatMessage', 'The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in message file for %2.')
```

What does this mean and what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: When you get this error, are you actually using ```"mybody"``` as the body of the message?

Comment: i Will use `smtplib` module

Comment: Yes, mybody is just a string placeholder for some HTML code that I will generate later.

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem using 2.7.6

Comment: I have one computer in which it works fine on. I don't think this matters but it does not work for me on a virtual machine.

Comment: @user2242044, You should include those sorts of details in the question, they matter

Comment: @wnnmaw just updated the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Is outlook installed on the virtual machine?

Comment: yes, it is installed. I can switch ` newMail.Send() ` ` newMail.Display() ` and a email pops up. I can also send emails manually through Outlook.

Comment: Solved the issue!! It appears that Outlook has some security in place to prevent automated emails. Not sure how to work around this, but I know the issue.

Comment: @user2242044 Could you add a real answer to this then? I have seen your post like 2h ago, but didn't care to read all the comments. Now I arrived at the same conclusion and wanted to come back to leave a comment and read yours. A more prominent answer could be helpful for some future superficial people :).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you solved this issue? @user2242044